# Behaviour of Python all() operator

Tags: python

have a question on all() operator in Python.
say

```
array = ["one","one","one"]
all( x=="one" for x in array )  <<--- i want to check for all "one" in array
```

The above seem to work. however, if i have

```
array = []
all( x=="one" for x in array )  <<--- this still return true to me.
```

The behaviour is that i want it return false if all items are not "one". How to do it? thanks

Comment: All 0 of the items in the list are `"one"`. This is a [vacuous truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). You seem to think that it isn't the case that all items in the list are `"one"`; I recommend reading up on vacuous truth so you don't needlessly complicate your logic excluding empty lists when they should really be accepted.

Comment: As @user2357112 pointed out, this is simple math: For all elements of `array` your proposition holds.

Answer (score 1):

You can read `all()` as if it means:

> It returns `False` if any of the items evaluates to `False`. `True` otherwise.

So an empty set will return `True`, because there is none that will make it false.

Generally speaking, in an empty set, all the elements fullfill any requirement you can imagine. That's a principle of logic, not of Python, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

`all`'s implementation is equivalent to [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

So, it returns `True` till any of the elements in the iterable is Falsy. In your case that didnt happen. Thats why it returns `True`

Comment: hi thanks. so in order to do what i want, i can include another statement, : if array and all( x=="one" for x in array ) . Is that correct? I just want it not to be empty array, and all elements is "one". thanks

Comment: @dorothy Thats correct :)

Answer (score 1):

> How to do it?

```
array and all(x=="one" for x in array)
```

Empty lists are false, so the result is false and it doesn't matter that the `all` part is true.

If you want to deal with iterables other than containers like `list` then it's a bit harder. I suppose you need something like this:

```
set(x=="one" for x in iterable) == { True }
```

Although if you care about speed, the following should be faster on the whole, since the version above doesn't short-circuit like `all` does:

```
def nonempty_all(iterable):
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    try:
        if not next(iterator):
            return False
    except StopIteration:
        return False
    return all(iterator)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`all`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#all) always returns `True` for an empty list/tuple/etc.  This is because, technically, every item in an empty collection fulfills any and every condition there is.

To fix the problem, you need to add some additional code to test whether your list is empty or not.  Fortunately, empty lists evaluate to `False` in Python, so you can just do this:

```
>>> array = []
>>> bool(array and all(x=="one" for x in array))
False
>>> if array and all(x=="one" for x in array):
...     print True
... else:
...     print False
...
False
>>>
```